# How can I use attributes to change color

Tags: luatex

`LuaTeX` defines `attributes`.

Consider the following snippet (to be compiled with `luatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newattribute\testattr
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{color1}{red}
\colorlet{color2}{blue}

\begin{document}

Test \setattribute\testattr{1} Test1 \setattribute\testattr{2} Test2

\end{document}
```

How can I use the value of attribute `\testattr` so that `Test1` would be in red and `Test2` would be in blue?

Comment: Have you looked over the code in [`luacolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/luacolor)?

Comment: @JosephWright No I haven't but it looks Indeed promising. Would you mind writing an answer?

Comment: I don't think it is fair to describe it as 'not documented'. The manual devotes considerable space to the code and breaks it down with some commentary. Maybe not sufficient explanation for you, but that's not the same as its being entirely undocumented.

Comment: @cfr Well, ok. Let me rephrase. I spent some time trying to figure out how ’traverse’ fonction works and, as I said, as a beginner in this field (node list manipulation, hlists, callbacks, etc), it is not that easy. Of course, Heiko's packages are amazing and his answers here are great. Sorry for being unfair on that matter.

Comment: That's fair. I don't understand any of it either. But I suspect Heiko would have to write several volumes to explain it from scratch ;).